# How to emulate many bluetooth devices via a computer

Tags: bluetooth, emulation

I'm working on a project that requires emulating multiple Bluetooth devices through a computer. I need to simulate the presence of a fleet of Bluetooth devices for testing and development purposes. I have searched online, but I haven't found many resources that address this specific scenario.

Does anyone have experience or knowledge on how to emulate multiple Bluetooth devices through a computer? I would like to be able to create these virtual devices so that they can be detected and interact with real Bluetooth devices. Additionally, it would be helpful to have control over the features and properties of the emulated virtual devices (Such as the name by which it is detected by other devices).

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What OS are you looking to do this on?

Comment: @ukBaz Windows 10/11 or Ubuntu 22+

Comment: The official Bluetooth stack on Linux (BlueZ) has a Bluetooth emulator called `btvirt` which they use in their testing. I've only seen limited documentation: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/emulator/main.c#n42. These virtual devices do not broadcast over the air so will only be detectable by the BlueZ stack on the same machine. If you want something to actually be detectable over the air then multiple USB dongles where you load example advertisements and gatt servers like the ones at https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test could be an option.

Comment: It seems like you talk against yourself when you say you want "emulated", "virtual" devices that shall still be able to interact with "real" Bluetooth devices. So... do you want a emulated/virtual setup or a real setup? Or do you want to use a single (real) Bluetooth radio that using time slicing acts as multiple devices?

Comment: @Emil I want multiple Bluetooth devices A1, A2, ..., An to be displayed from one device A.

Comment: If you use static random address, you can tell the hci controller to change the address every time before you start advertising. Then every advertising session will appear coming from different devices. Not sure how to do that on the OS level though.

Comment: @Emil Ideally you would have a script to run so if you have any ideas about a program to create that would be ideal

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely not possible. The problem isn't software; it's the antenna and strict timing requirements. You cannot advertise as a large number of different BLE devices on a single antenna, and to even advertise as more than one (which I can imagine, but never seen), you would have to have complete control of the hardware driver. Being able to hit the timing intervals for more than a few does not sound practical.

The solution is to install multiple Bluetooth cards/dongles so that you have multiple antennas, or similarly to use more dedicated devices like an ESP32 or nRF52 DK (they generally cost $20-$30 each). I generally recommend that latter, but you need to be a bit more comfortable with embedded development.